# How to define optional methods in a Swift protocol with Swift parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

### TL;DR

How can I define optional methods in a swift protocol that accept custom typed parameters?

### The case

I understand that the way to define optional methods in a swift protocol is using the `@objc` flag. Like so:

```
@objc protocol someSweetProtocol {
    optional func doSomethingCool()
}
```

But when I wanted to use my custom type for the parameter, like so:

```
@objc protocol someSweetProtocol {
    optional func doSomethingCool(: HSCoolPerson)
}
```

I got this error:

[image]

Which is not cool.

How can this problem be solved? Also can you explain why this is happening?

### Addendum

This is how `HSCoolPerson` is defined:

```
class HSCoolPerson {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Nothing special there...

Comment: How is HSCoolPerson defined? It would have to be a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: "Nothing special there..." And that's exactly the problem! See my answer below.

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer, I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
class HSCoolPerson {
    // ...
}
```

As the error message plainly tells you, that type, the class HSCoolPerson, is completely invisible to Objective-C. And a protocol optional method is an Objective-C language feature; Swift merely borrows it, as it were. (That's why you have to say `@objc protocol` to get this feature.) So any time you want to define a protocol optional method, you have to do it in a way that Objective-C can understand, because it is Objective-C that is going to do the work for you.

To expose this class to Objective-C, simply derive it from NSObject:

```
class HSCoolPerson : NSObject {
    // ...
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: And see my online Swift book for a list of what Swift things Objective-C can and can't see: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects

Comment: "Swift merely borrows it, as it were." - Any idea why they didn't build optional protocol methods right into Swift itself? Maybe there's an obvious reason I'm missing.

Comment: @TimVermeulen I can only guess: I suspect that they would rather not have had this feature at all, but they simply had to mirror what Objective-C does, for compatibility, especially because so many Cocoa protocols rely on this feature. The case is thus similar to that of AnyObject, whose real _raison d'être_ is to have something for Objective-C `id` to correspond to.

Comment: I was under the impression that there would be a Swift way of doing it.
Thanks though, works great, and is clean.
I guess that's what you get when you're trying to make 2 seperate languages compatible.

Comment: @MrHaze Perhaps I should say "Cocoa" instead of saying "Objective-C". But it amounts to the same thing. Try to say `@objc protocol P {}` in a playground where you do _not_ import Foundation (or UIKit or anything else that itself imports Foundation). The playground squawks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the default implementations in an extension, like so:

```
class HSCoolPerson {}

protocol SomeSweetProtocol {
    func doSomethingCool()
}

extension SomeSweetProtocol {
    func doSomethingCool(: HSCoolPerson) {
        // default implementation here
    }
}

class SomeSweetClass: SomeSweetProtocol {
    // no implementation of doSomethingCool(_:) here, and no errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare func like that in protocol

```
@objc optional func doSomethingCool(: HSCoolPerson)
```